# Drawing circle following the points touched on the screen by user

Tags: java, android, animation, touch

I am trying to make the circles which follow the user's finger touch.
But for some reason, this is not working correctly.

```
private void onTouchMovement() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; i++) {
            final int finalI = i;
            circles[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (view.getId() != circle_ids[finalI]) return false;
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            view.setX(event.getX()-CircleRadius);
                            view.setY(event.getY()-CircleRadius);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
       }
```

Comment: What does it actually do?

Comment: the circles "oscillate".
Let me clear that up..
Imagine two parallel lines.
One line at which the center of the circle and the touch sequence lies, and another parallel to it at some distance, say 30 dp(this distance changes each time).
The circle gets drawn on both the lines back and forth very fast.

Comment: I found the solution myself. I should be using "getRawX" and "getRawY" instead of "getX" and "getY". God knows why :P  but it works